# Issues passing Google Analytics cookie ( _ga ) from landing page to store cart

Tags: google-analytics, bigcommerce

I have a landing page on an external website. 
With the `"add to cart"` function of `"cart.php?action=add&product_id="`.

Google Analytics adds a cookie to the end of the link `"&_ga=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`. 
When the `"add to cart"` button is clicked, the product is added to the cart on my store, but the `"_ga="` cookie is stripped and I lose the tracking cookie. 
The cart page ends up showing `"cart.php?suggest=5670133a10fcf"` and has removed the `"_ga="` cookie.

Does anyone have any suggestions on things that can be done to correct this?

Comment: This sounds like you are tracking across domains between your site and the cart page. Can you confirm? Also are you using GTM?

Comment: Yes, I just implemented cross domain tracking from an external domain "wpfilms.co" (for landing pages) to my store / cart page "store.wpfilm.com". Right now I am not using GTM.

Comment: Make sure you have set up the tracking code correctly for x-domain tracking, including 1) allowLinker, 2) require linker, 3) setting up auto-link domains.

Comment: The Google Analytic cross domain tracking code is correct. I had Google's help in setting up the cross domain tracking correctly. Per Google, everything is setup correctly with the only issue that they see is the "add to cart" link function stripping the "_ga" cookie.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the code. Maybe the add-to-cart button has a javascript function attached that overrides the decorated form action or link (because the redirect or form submit is done within a function that sets a different href/action) and so the param get's lost. Happened to me one or two times.

Comment: The external domain that I have the landing page on is: http://wpfilms.co/rental-upgrade17/ which has an "add to cart" button that goes to http://store.wpfilm.com